# CVAT: How to install from submodules for serverless

Tags: opencv, serverless, cvat

I want to make a serverless function. The main logic has been encapsulated in a submodule repo, the  `model_handler.py` will just call the content of the submodule.

location:

```yaml
CVAT
|----serverless
      |------------modules
                     |-------------------some-foo
```

in `function-gpu.yaml`  I added following:

```yaml
        - Kind: ADD
          value: ./modules/some-foo /home/user/
        - kind: RUN
          value: pip3 install /home/user/modules/some-foo
```

But the `./modules/some-foo` cannot be found  while running `serverless/deploy_gpu.sh` ie.

Any idea, thank you!

Comment: you'll have better luck asking about this on the cvat github. it's not an issue as such but you could spin this as "lacking documentation" for your usecase.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz did , no response yet